# Searching a SQL table by key

Tags: sql, key, where-clause

I have set up a table in SQL where one field is named "key" but when I try to enquire on that field I get a syntax error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key'".

Comment: `key` is a SQL keyword.  You need to escape it.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 2):

'key' is a SQL keyword. When you use a keyword as column name, you should use backtick escaping.

Hope the below sample code helps you to understand.

Table Creation

```
CREATE table table1(name varchar(5), `key` int);
```

Inserting data into table

```
insert into table1 values('A',1);
insert into table1 values('B',2);
```

Retrieving data from table

```
SELECT name, `key` from table1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e1040/3

Comment: Is that a single apostrophe or two?

Comment: @nelson That is non-standard SQL. In standard SQL you need double quotes: e.g. `"KEY"`.

Comment: It is a backquote symbol. Look for the symbol ~ on the keyboard. It is usually below escape key.